# Es posible programar tareas con `at` y pasarle como parámetros la hora actual con algunas operaciones

Tags: linux, terminal

En GNU/Linux puedo usar el comando AT, entre otros, para programar tareas algo así:

```
# at 07:07 
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> ejecutar_la_tarea_que_sea
at> <EOT>
```

hasta aquí sin problemas la duda que me surge es, 
- ¿Es posible?, y si lo es ¿cómo puedo hacer para que tome el tiempo del sistema y le aplique una operación algo así?

```
#at get_hora_actual + 25_minutos
```

me gustaría que de ser posible no se tenga que usar ningún script.

P.D: *según [esto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio) creo que la pregunta es válida para el sitio*

Answer (score 2):

Lo que comentas se puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
> at $(date -d "+25 min" +"%H:%M")
```

El comando **`date`** permite sumar y restar años, meses, días, horas, minutos y segundos. Eso si, debes especificarlo en inglés y en singular(**year**, **month**, **day**, **hour**, **min**, **second**).

Comment: gracias por responder estaba esperando, a ver si contestaba alguien, puede ver la respuesta que obtuve. Saludos

Comment: De nada, aunque sip habría sido más fácil tirar del man directamente, ahí explica lo que pusiste abajo XDDD

Answer (score 2):

Obtuve esta forma de hacerlo usando `now` por ejemplo asi:

```
$ at now + 25 minutes
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo "foo" > /home/your_home/at.out
at> <EOT>
job 20 at Wed Apr 12 11:21:00 2017
```

[original respuesta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358577/it-is-possible-to-schedule-tasks-with-at-and-pass-the-current-time-as-a-paramete#358580) de **steeldriver** en [`Unix & Linux`](http://unix.stackexchange.com)